# The Windows Live ID Service is unavailable at the moment

Tags: sync, microsoft-account, htc, 7.x

I have a HTC Titan on WP7, I'm using the GiffGaff network.

I have a recurring problem where every couple of day features involving my Live account stop working. The market place gives the following error: "The window lives id service is unavailable at the moment", the office application is unable to sync and XBOX live is unable to sync as well.

I can fix this by running through the connection setup again, however having to do this every few days isn't my ideal long term solution.

Anyone got any ideas? What's causing the problem? How can I resolve it? How can I get more information about the problem?

I'm happy to receive technical answers or even just ideas on how to get debugging information for this.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I'm also in the UK, but on a different network, but have also seen similar issues on and off for a few days. In my case, waiting and retrying has been sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

error: "The window lives id service is unavailable at the moment" on Windows phone is just due to old version of WP7 software on your windows phone basically. This error can be finished by few easy and quick steps.

1. Install Zune software on your computer (http://support.xbox.com/en-US/zune/software/
   download)
2. After Zune software installation open Zune
3. you need to connect your windows phone with your Pc(computer)
4. sign in with your Live, Hotmail or Msn ID's
5. 1st thing is to do just get connect your phone with Zune and install updates on your
   windows phone(WP7) 
   6   Just wait to complete all updates on your windows phone(WP7)

and thats it, your phone is ready to use with your ID's

Comment: Possibly, I havnt seen the issue in a while, but I'm pretty sure my phone was up to date at the time.